# Prevent Autocomplete suggest list after entery key is press

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, autocomplete

I have implemented the jquery autocomplete plugin in knockout and it's features is working fine.

There is a requirement tag and keyword search. When the data from autosuggest is tag search and manually typed is keyword search, it will perform the search after hitting the enter key.

Here comes the problem when I type some keyword and hit the enter key the  textinput value should be formed as taggedit style  control and the auto suggest is loading after some delay and it should not in this case. When I chose the data from suggested list and hitting the enter key is working fine.

How to prevent the auto suggest list after type and hitting the enter key **if there is a delay in loading.**

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```
$(function() {

    var availableTags = [
            "item1","item2","item3"
        ];

    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source:availableTags,
        minLength: 0
    }).keyup(function (e) {
        if(e.which === 13) {
            $(".ui-menu-item").hide();
        }            
    });
});​
```

Comment: sorry Darcey, I don't want  the item to be focus when i hit enter key instead of that i need to close the suggest list  after enter key is pressed.if there is some delay.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will this work if the ajax call started and hit the enter key?.Because im setting the datasource from the remote webapi.

Comment: i'm not 100% sure test it out :) Also take a further look at http://www.laktek.com/2011/03/03/introducing-jquery-smart-autocomplete/ and do some more googleing to find out. Part of programming fun is the stressful bugs you encounter :D

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code to make it work .But looking for a better solution.

```
      keyup(function (e) {
      if(e.which === 13) {
                   $("#txtSearchAuto").autocomplete({
                        disabled: true
                    });                       
                }
```

and added the style in the css

.ui-autocomplete-disabled{display:none !important}

and finally enabling the autocomplete in the textbox key up event

```
          if (event.keyCode !== 13){
           if (self.SearchInput().length >=2)
            $("#txtSearchAuto").autocomplete({
                disabled: false
            });
           }
```